# How to implement interface methods in java?

Tags: java, oop

I have some strange question.

I have an interface in java:

```
public interface Inventory{
public void add(// take an object of a class);
public int delete(// take an object of a class);
public int edit(// take an object of a class);
}
```

then i wrote a class that implements the interface.

```
public class Supply implements Inventory{
public void add( // object of some class) {}
public int edit( // object of some class) {}
public int delete( // object of some class) {}
}
```

then i wrote another class that implements the interface but with different object name in parentheses.

```
public class support implements Inventory{
public void add(// object of different class) {}
public int edit(// object of different class) {}
public int delete(// object of different class) {}
}
```

my question is: what is the parameter that must be written in interface methods in order to make the other classes take any object name that would like to implement in its own way.

Comment: Are you talking about generics? E.g. `List<T>`?

Comment: no, for example if method body in interface takes an object called `Product p` then this object name must be used also in all classes that implements the interface. but i have a class that needs different object name called for example: `Supplier s`

Comment: Method body in interface ??

Comment: That is what generics are for. You can have an interface `Inventory<T>` with a method `void add(T t)`. Then you can have a class that `implements Inventory<Product>` with a method `add(Product p)` but you could also have a class that `implements Inventory<Supplier>` with a method `void add(Supplier s)`.

Comment: I mean inside the method parentheses, yes

Comment: @PaulBoddington this is the best answer for my question, thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what generics are for. You can have an interface `Inventory<T>` with a method `void add(T t)`. Then you can have a class that implements `Inventory<Product>` with a method `add(Product p)` but you could also have a class that implements `Inventory<Supplier>` with a method `void add(Supplier s)`.